# JPA - bind entites via primary key - Invalid identifier ORA error

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql, jpa-2.1

I have the following two tables in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT (
    ID NUMBER(19, 0) NOT NULL,
    AA_ID VARCHAR2(11 CHAR),
    BB_ID VARCHAR2(8 CHAR),
    STATUS NUMBER(1, 0) DEFAULT 1,
    CREATED_AT TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL,
    LAST_MODIFIED_AT TIMESTAMP(6)
) TABLESPACE $tbsp;

CREATE TABLE MOBILE_INSTANCE (
    ID NUMBER(19, 0) NOT NULL,
    ACCOUNT_ID NUMBER(19, 0) NOT NULL,
    APPLICATION_ID VARCHAR2(36 CHAR) NOT NULL,
    TOKEN VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) NOT NULL,
    DEVICE VARCHAR2(13 CHAR),
    STATUS VARCHAR2(10 CHAR),
    CREATED_AT TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL,
    LAST_MODIFIED_AT TIMESTAMP(6)
) TABLESPACE $tbsp;
```

And the connection between them:

```
ALTER TABLE MOBILEBANK_INSTANCE ADD CONSTRAINT FK_MOBILEBANKINSTANCE_ACCOUNT FOREIGN KEY (ACCOUNT_ID) REFERENCES ACCOUNT(ID);
```

So far, this is working like a charm...

Via JPA, I have created the entites for these tables - please see the following snippet of my entities:

In the MobileInstance entity I have marked the @ManyToOne connection as following:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ACCOUNT_ID")
    private Account accountId;
```

And this is how it looks like in my Account entity class:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "accountId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<MobileInstance> mobileInstanceList = new ArrayList<>();
```

As you see, the accountId field (which is in the Account table actually a Long value) is marked as an Account object.

Later on, when I have already an account object, I whish the create a mobileInstance object as well, with the appropiate account ID.

But when I call:

```
mobileInstance.setAccountId
```

it requieres an account parameter... When I assigne one to it and try to save it in the DB, I got the error:

```
ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:131 - ORA-00904: "APPLICATION_ID": invalid identifier
```

I assume, it is because the Application ID field in the Database is a Number field, and I assigne to it a whole Account object which I do not want to change to Long..

Is there a way the code to recognize that only use the primary key of my Account table?

Comment: Note that the error is about `APPLICATION_ID` , not `ACCOUNT_ID` .

Comment: And please, rename your field (and its getter and setter) from `accountId`to `account`. It's not an ID. It's an account.

Comment: Is there an example of Account object and MobileInstance object? I am suspicious that you have an applicationId that should not be null in your MobileInstance object.

Comment: @JBNizet is creating sql table manually is good approach ?